# create order programmatically - model retrieve error instead of object

Tags: orders, model

Im trying to programmatically create an order. I created a model with the following structure:

```
<?php
class Pricebinc_App_Model_OrderCreate extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const CUSTOMER_RANDOM = null;
    protected $_shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    protected $_paymentMethod = 'cashondelivery';
    protected $_customer = self::CUSTOMER_RANDOM;
    protected $_subTotal = 0;
    protected $_order;
    protected $_storeId;

    public function setShippingMethod($methodName)
    {
        $this->_shippingMethod = $methodName;
    }

    public function setPaymentMethod($methodName)
    {
        $this->_paymentMethod = $methodName;
    }

    public function setCustomer($customer)
    {
        if ($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
            $this->_customer = $customer;
        }
        if (is_numeric($customer)) {
            $this->_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer);
        } else if ($customer === self::CUSTOMER_RANDOM) {
            $customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

            $customers
                ->getSelect()
                ->limit(1)
                ->order('RAND()');

            $id = $customers->getFirstItem()->getId();

            $this->_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
        }
    }

    public function createOrder($products)
    {
        if (!($this->_customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)) {
            $this->setCustomer(self::CUSTOMER_RANDOM);
        }

        $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
        $this->_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('order')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId($this->_storeId);

        $currencyCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setQuoteId(0)
            ->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setStoreCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setOrderCurrencyCode($currencyCode);


        $this->_order->setCustomerEmail($this->_customer->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerFirstname($this->_customer->getFirstname())
            ->setCustomerLastname($this->_customer->getLastname())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($this->_customer->getGroupId())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
            ->setCustomer($this->_customer);


        $billing = $this->_customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
            ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
            ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultBilling())
            ->setCustomerAddress_id($billing->getEntityId())
            ->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
            ->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
            ->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
            ->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
            ->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
            ->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
            ->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
            ->setCity($billing->getCity())
            ->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
            ->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
            ->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
            ->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
            ->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
            ->setFax($billing->getFax());
        $this->_order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

        $shipping = $this->_customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
            ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
            ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultShipping())
            ->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
            ->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
            ->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
            ->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
            ->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
            ->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
            ->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
            ->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
            ->setCity($shipping->getCity())
            ->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
            ->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
            ->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
            ->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
            ->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
            ->setFax($shipping->getFax());

        $this->_order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
            ->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingMethod);

        $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
            ->setMethod($this->_paymentMethod)
            ->setPoNumber(' – ');

        $this->_order->setPayment($orderPayment);

        $this->_addProducts($products);

        $this->_order->setSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setBaseSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setGrandTotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setBaseGrandTotal($this->_subTotal);

        $transaction->addObject($this->_order);
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'place'));
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'save'));
        $transaction->save();
    }

    protected function _addProducts($products)
    {
        $this->_subTotal = 0;

        foreach ($products as $productRequest) {
            if ($productRequest['product'] == 'rand') {

                $productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

                $productsCollection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
                Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productsCollection);

                $productsCollection->getSelect()
                    ->order('RAND()')
                    ->limit(rand($productRequest['min'], $productRequest['max']));

                foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
                    $this->_addProduct(array(
                        'product' => $product->getId(),
                        'qty' => rand(1, 2)
                    ));
                }
            } else {
                $this->_addProduct($productRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _addProduct($requestData)
    {
        $request = new Varien_Object();
        $request->setData($requestData);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($request['product']);

        $cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->prepareForCartAdvanced($request, $product);

        if (is_string($cartCandidates)) {
            throw new Exception($cartCandidates);
        }

        if (!is_array($cartCandidates)) {
            $cartCandidates = array($cartCandidates);
        }

        $parentItem = null;
        $errors = array();
        $items = array();
        foreach ($cartCandidates as $candidate) {
            $item = $this->_productToOrderItem($candidate, $candidate->getCartQty());

            $items[] = $item;

            /**
             * As parent item we should always use the item of first added product
             */
            if (!$parentItem) {
                $parentItem = $item;
            }
            if ($parentItem && $candidate->getParentProductId()) {
                $item->setParentItem($parentItem);
            }
            /**
             * We specify qty after we know about parent (for stock)
             */
            $item->setQty($item->getQty() + $candidate->getCartQty());

            // collect errors instead of throwing first one
            if ($item->getHasError()) {
                $message = $item->getMessage();
                if (!in_array($message, $errors)) { // filter duplicate messages
                    $errors[] = $message;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            Mage::throwException(implode("\n", $errors));
        }

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->_order->addItem($item);
        }

        return $items;
    }

    function _productToOrderItem(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
    {
        $rowTotal = $product->getFinalPrice() * $qty;

        $options = $product->getCustomOptions();

        $optionsByCode = array();

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $quoteOption = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->setData($option->getData())
                ->setProduct($option->getProduct());

            $optionsByCode[$quoteOption->getCode()] = $quoteOption;
        }

        $product->setCustomOptions($optionsByCode);

        $options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);

        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setQuoteItemId(0)
            ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
            ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
            ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
            ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
            ->setName($product->getName())
            ->setSku($product->getSku())
            ->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setBasePrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setOriginalPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setWeeeTaxApplied(serialize(array()))
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
            ->setProductOptions($options);

        $this->_subTotal += $rowTotal;

        return $orderItem;
    }
}

Then I include the following statement in the controller:

        $orderGenerator = Mage::getModel('app/ordercreate');

        $orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
            array(
                'product' => 24, //product id
                'qty' => 1
            )
        ));
```

But I constantly receive error 500.

I took that code from amasty https://blog.amasty.com/creating-magento-order-programmatically/

---

UPDATE:

finally this is the code if you need to create an order programmatically in magento 1.9.

```
<?php
class NameApp_App_Model_OrderCreate extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const CUSTOMER_RANDOM = null;
    protected $_shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    protected $_paymentMethod = 'cashondelivery';
    protected $_subTotal = 0;
    protected $_order;
    protected $_storeId = '0';

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('app/ordercreate');
    }

    public function setShippingMethod($methodName)
    {
        $this->_shippingMethod = $methodName;
    }
    public function setPaymentMethod($methodName)
    {
        $this->_paymentMethod = $methodName;
    }

    public function createOrder($products)
    {
        $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
        $this->_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('order')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId($this->_storeId);

        $currencyCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setQuoteId(0)
            ->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setStoreCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setOrderCurrencyCode($currencyCode);


        $this->_order->setCustomerEmail($this->_customer->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerFirstname($this->_customer->getFirstname())
            ->setCustomerLastname($this->_customer->getLastname())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($this->_customer->getGroupId())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
            ->setCustomer($this->_customer);


        $billing = $this->_customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
            ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
            ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultBilling())
            ->setCustomerAddress_id($billing->getEntityId())
            ->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
            ->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
            ->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
            ->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
            ->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
            ->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
            ->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
            ->setCity($billing->getCity())
            ->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
            ->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
            ->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
            ->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
            ->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
            ->setFax($billing->getFax());
        $this->_order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

        $shipping = $this->_customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
            ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
            ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultShipping())
            ->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
            ->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
            ->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
            ->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
            ->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
            ->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
            ->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
            ->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
            ->setCity($shipping->getCity())
            ->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
            ->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
            ->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
            ->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
            ->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
            ->setFax($shipping->getFax());

        $this->_order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
            ->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingMethod);

        $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
            ->setMethod($this->_paymentMethod)
            ->setPoNumber(' – ');

        $this->_order->setPayment($orderPayment);

        $this->_addProducts($products);

        $this->_order->setSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setBaseSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setGrandTotal($this->_subTotal)
            ->setBaseGrandTotal($this->_subTotal);

        $transaction->addObject($this->_order);
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'place'));
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'save'));
        $transaction->save();
    }

    protected function _addProducts($products)
    {
        $this->_subTotal = 0;

        foreach ($products as $productRequest) {
            if ($productRequest['product'] == 'rand') {

                $productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

                $productsCollection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
                Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productsCollection);

                $productsCollection->getSelect()
                    ->order('RAND()')
                    ->limit(rand($productRequest['min'], $productRequest['max']));

                foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
                    $this->_addProduct(array(
                        'product' => $product->getId(),
                        'qty' => rand(1, 2)
                    ));
                }
            } else {
                $this->_addProduct($productRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _addProduct($requestData)
    {
        $request = new Varien_Object();
        $request->setData($requestData);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($request['product']);

        $cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->prepareForCartAdvanced($request, $product);

        if (is_string($cartCandidates)) {
            throw new Exception($cartCandidates);
        }

        if (!is_array($cartCandidates)) {
            $cartCandidates = array($cartCandidates);
        }

        $parentItem = null;
        $errors = array();
        $items = array();
        foreach ($cartCandidates as $candidate) {
            $item = $this->_productToOrderItem($candidate, $candidate->getCartQty());

            $items[] = $item;

            /**
             * As parent item we should always use the item of first added product
             */
            if (!$parentItem) {
                $parentItem = $item;
            }
            if ($parentItem && $candidate->getParentProductId()) {
                $item->setParentItem($parentItem);
            }
            /**
             * We specify qty after we know about parent (for stock)
             */
            $item->setQty($item->getQty() + $candidate->getCartQty());

            // collect errors instead of throwing first one
            if ($item->getHasError()) {
                $message = $item->getMessage();
                if (!in_array($message, $errors)) { // filter duplicate messages
                    $errors[] = $message;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            Mage::throwException(implode("\n", $errors));
        }

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->_order->addItem($item);
        }

        return $items;
    }

    function _productToOrderItem(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
    {
        $rowTotal = $product->getFinalPrice() * $qty;

        $options = $product->getCustomOptions();

        $optionsByCode = array();

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $quoteOption = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->setData($option->getData())
                ->setProduct($option->getProduct());

            $optionsByCode[$quoteOption->getCode()] = $quoteOption;
        }

        $product->setCustomOptions($optionsByCode);

        $options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);

        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setQuoteItemId(0)
            ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
            ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
            ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
            ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
            ->setName($product->getName())
            ->setSku($product->getSku())
            ->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setBasePrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setOriginalPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setWeeeTaxApplied(serialize(array()))
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
            ->setProductOptions($options);

        $this->_subTotal += $rowTotal;

        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from controller:

```
    $orderGenerator = Mage::getModel('app/ordercreate');

    $orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
        array(
            'product' => 41, //product id
            'qty' => 1
        )
    ));
```

thats it. you can make product => 41 dynamic instead of static. its your choice.

Comment: @meenakshi-sundaram-r thanks for the corrections

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please see below

Comment: @willemwigman yes I have 4. even if I forced the customerid to an existing one eg: 2 , zend debugger says _customer=2 and receive same error with _customer details. weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function createOrder() on Model initialization (which needs arguments). 
So $orderGenerator = Mage::getModel('app/ordercreate')->createOrder(); will throw an error.

Try:

```
$orderGenerator = Mage::getModel('app/ordercreate'); // removed ->createOrder()

$orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
        array(
            'product' => 24, //product id
            'qty' => 1
        )
    ));
```

---

Following up on your new edit (with customer error). Do you have any customers in your store? If not, create a customer first, otherwise the script can't get any random customer to attach the order to.

---

So, as you found out partly yourself, the customer-load function didn't work. Why would still be an interesting question though. Here's the working code, although it could still use some improvements (or have a look at this [online diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/np94nzzf)):

```
<?php
 class NameApp_App_Model_OrderCreate extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
const CUSTOMER_RANDOM = null;
protected $_shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
protected $_paymentMethod = 'cashondelivery';
protected $_subTotal = 0;
protected $_order;
protected $_storeId = '0';

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('app/ordercreate');
}

public function setShippingMethod($methodName)
{
    $this->_shippingMethod = $methodName;
}
public function setPaymentMethod($methodName)
{
    $this->_paymentMethod = $methodName;
}

public function createOrder($products)
{
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
    $this->_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getEntityType('order')
        ->fetchNewIncrementId($this->_storeId);

    $currencyCode = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
        ->setQuoteId(0)
        ->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
        ->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
        ->setStoreCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
        ->setOrderCurrencyCode($currencyCode);


    $this->_order->setCustomerEmail($this->_customer->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerFirstname($this->_customer->getFirstname())
        ->setCustomerLastname($this->_customer->getLastname())
        ->setCustomerGroupId($this->_customer->getGroupId())
        ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
        ->setCustomer($this->_customer);


    $billing = $this->_customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
        ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
        ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
        ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultBilling())
        ->setCustomerAddress_id($billing->getEntityId())
        ->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
        ->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
        ->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
        ->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
        ->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
        ->setCity($billing->getCity())
        ->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
        ->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
        ->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
        ->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
        ->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
        ->setFax($billing->getFax());
    $this->_order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

    $shipping = $this->_customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
        ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
        ->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId())
        ->setCustomerAddressId($this->_customer->getDefaultShipping())
        ->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
        ->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
        ->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
        ->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
        ->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
        ->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
        ->setCity($shipping->getCity())
        ->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
        ->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
        ->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
        ->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
        ->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
        ->setFax($shipping->getFax());

    $this->_order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
        ->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingMethod);

    $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
        ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
        ->setMethod($this->_paymentMethod)
        ->setPoNumber(' – ');

    $this->_order->setPayment($orderPayment);

    $this->_addProducts($products);

    $this->_order->setSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
        ->setBaseSubtotal($this->_subTotal)
        ->setGrandTotal($this->_subTotal)
        ->setBaseGrandTotal($this->_subTotal);

    $transaction->addObject($this->_order);
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'place'));
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($this->_order, 'save'));
    $transaction->save();
}

protected function _addProducts($products)
{
    $this->_subTotal = 0;

    foreach ($products as $productRequest) {
        if ($productRequest['product'] == 'rand') {

            $productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

            $productsCollection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productsCollection);

            $productsCollection->getSelect()
                ->order('RAND()')
                ->limit(rand($productRequest['min'], $productRequest['max']));

            foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
                $this->_addProduct(array(
                    'product' => $product->getId(),
                    'qty' => rand(1, 2)
                ));
            }
        } else {
            $this->_addProduct($productRequest);
        }
    }
}

protected function _addProduct($requestData)
{
    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($requestData);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($request['product']);

    $cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->prepareForCartAdvanced($request, $product);

    if (is_string($cartCandidates)) {
        throw new Exception($cartCandidates);
    }

    if (!is_array($cartCandidates)) {
        $cartCandidates = array($cartCandidates);
    }

    $parentItem = null;
    $errors = array();
    $items = array();
    foreach ($cartCandidates as $candidate) {
        $item = $this->_productToOrderItem($candidate, $candidate->getCartQty());

        $items[] = $item;

        /**
         * As parent item we should always use the item of first added product
         */
        if (!$parentItem) {
            $parentItem = $item;
        }
        if ($parentItem && $candidate->getParentProductId()) {
            $item->setParentItem($parentItem);
        }
        /**
         * We specify qty after we know about parent (for stock)
         */
        $item->setQty($item->getQty() + $candidate->getCartQty());

        // collect errors instead of throwing first one
        if ($item->getHasError()) {
            $message = $item->getMessage();
            if (!in_array($message, $errors)) { // filter duplicate messages
                $errors[] = $message;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        Mage::throwException(implode("\n", $errors));
    }

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $this->_order->addItem($item);
    }

    return $items;
}

function _productToOrderItem(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
{
    $rowTotal = $product->getFinalPrice() * $qty;

    $options = $product->getCustomOptions();

    $optionsByCode = array();

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $quoteOption = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->setData($option->getData())
            ->setProduct($option->getProduct());

        $optionsByCode[$quoteOption->getCode()] = $quoteOption;
    }

    $product->setCustomOptions($optionsByCode);

    $options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);

    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
        ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
        ->setQuoteItemId(0)
        ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
        ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
        ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
        ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
        ->setName($product->getName())
        ->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
        ->setBasePrice($product->getFinalPrice())
        ->setOriginalPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
        ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setWeeeTaxApplied(serialize(array()))
        ->setBaseWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
        ->setWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
        ->setBaseWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
        ->setWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
        ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
        ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
        ->setWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
        ->setWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
        ->setProductOptions($options);

    $this->_subTotal += $rowTotal;

    return $orderItem;
}
```

}

Comment: Tested and can conform it works this way.

Comment: not working for me. are you testing in Magento 1.9? thanks in advance

Comment: absolutely. Is your model located at /app/code/[community or local]/Pricebinc/App/Model/OrderCreate.php ?

Is your custom extension "Pricebinc_App" loaded correctly? Does it show up in system>config>advanced>advanced (module output screen) ?

Comment: yes, everything is working ok. the module performs more functions and it´s working ok will all these. the problem is when I include another step to create an order in it.

Comment: Does the controller still work when you only include the first line? What happens when you include Zend_Debug::dump($orderGenerator); after initiating the Model?

Comment: it works, details edited in question

Comment: Then it's about time to check var/system.log and your servers www_error_log files. It's either that, if you have the access to the the server logs, or the 'hacky way'. Start commenting out functions in createOrder(), starting all the way down.

If you can get the last lines of the www_error_log and post it that would help.

Comment: thank you, finally i found it. your help was very appreciated, good tips on debugging for me. brgds!. ps: if you wanna paste the answer put it and I will mark your answer as correct. brgds

Comment: Nice. However, what customer is being loaded now? Since you're using "Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();".

Are you generating test-orders in bulk? For importing 'real' orders you would need to load the proper customer, right?

Wouldn't this be better? "$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
        $customer->setWebsiteId($this-> _storeId); 
        $customer->loadByEmail('customer@email.com);"
?

Comment: And thanks for giving me the 'correct answer'. I've included your code in the answer!

Comment: I changed that part to :         $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $this->_storeId = $this->_customer->getStoreId();